# Error de lógica con funciones en Python

Tags: python, funciones, lógica

¡Hola!
Estoy haciendo ejercicios con funciones en Python y me he atascado en uno. Llevo unas cuantas horas tratando de ver en que me estoy equivocando y no doy con ello.

**ENUNCIADO DEL EJERCICIO:
"Crea un programa que realice las siguientes tareas:
Paso 1) solicite al usuario una contraseña y la guarde en una variable
Paso 2) pida al usuario introducir la contraseña para loguearse
si la contraseña es correcta mostramos "Login correcto"
si la contraseña no es correcta se le tendrá que mostrar un mensaje de "Login fallido. Intento 1", donde 1 será una variable contador que irá incrementandose hasta llegar a 5. En ese punto reiniciamos el programa y volveremos al Paso 1"**

Lo hice anteriormente (porque así nos lo pedían) sin usar funciones, y funcionaba:

```
while True:
    password = input("¡Bienvenido!\nIntroduzca su nueva contraseña: ")
    user_password = password
    for i in range(5):                                         
        login = input("Para acceder introduzca su contraseña: ")
        if login == password:                                
            print("Login correcto, gracias")                
            break
        else:                                         
            fallos = i+1                              
            print(f"Login fallido. Intento {fallos}/5)")
    if login == password:        
        break
```

Ahora, como decía, debo repetirlo intentando usar las máximas funciones posibles. Aquí está mi código:

```
def user_password():
    password = input("¡Bienvenido!\nIntroduzca su nueva contraseña: ")
    return password
    
def login()
    login = input("Para acceder introduzca su contraseña: ")
    return login

def login_correcto(loginDevuelto, passwordDevuelto):
        return "Login correcto, gracias."

def login_incorrecto(loginDevuelto, passwordDevuelto):
    for i in range(4):
        if loginDevuelto != passwordDevuelto:
            fallos = i+2                                  
            print(input(f"Login fallido. Intento {fallos}/5: "))
        elif loginDevuelto == passwordDevuelto:
            return login_correcto(loginDevuelto, passwordDevuelto)
    else:
        return login()

passwordDevuelto = user_password()
loginDevuelto = login()
login_correcto(loginDevuelto, passwordDevuelto)
login_incorrecto(loginDevuelto, passwordDevuelto)
```

No sé si es un error de lógica en la función <login_incorrecto()>, un mal entendimiento de como se invocan las funciones y se comunican entre sí...
En cualquier caso no logro solucionar estos dos errores:
1). Que vuelva a empezar si llego al máximo de 5 errores.
2). Que me de por buena la contraseña si la escribo bien más allá del segundo intento.

¡Gracias de antemano, y perdón por lo largo del post!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

en efecto la lógica que estabas aplicando en login_incorrecto es errónea, a continuación te adjunto mi solución, espero que te sirva:

```
def user_password():
     return input("¡Bienvenido!\nIntroduzca su nueva contraseña: ")
    
def solicitar_login():
    return input("Para acceder introduzca su contraseña: ")
     
def login_correcto():
        print("Login correcto, gracias.")

def login_incorrecto(fallos):
        print(f"Login fallido. Intento {fallos}/5: ")

def comprobar_login(password):
    for i in range(5):
        if solicitar_login()==password:
            login_correcto()
            return True
        else:
            fallos = i + 1
            login_incorrecto(fallos)
    return False

def main():
    while True:
        passwordDevuelto = user_password()
        if comprobar_login(passwordDevuelto):
            break

main()
```

Como consejo, vete mirando paso a paso como funciona para que comprendas bien las llamadas a las funciones y como está funcionando. Luego intenta rehacerlo desde cero una vez lo hayas entendido.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por la ayuda, y sobre todo por el consejo. Voy a darle un buen repaso a tu código y todo el asunto de las funciones de nuevo :)